# Raspbian, gstreamer glimagesink without x

Tags: gstreamer

I am running a raspbian setup on my RPI4 which invokes a gstreamer pipeline upon startup. Part of this gstreamer pipeline is output to HDMI which I want to achieve without using X.

Gstreamers fbdev sink is too slow, so I wanted to use the glimagesink. Unfortunately this sink does produce strange results when I run it outside of X - the colors seem to be completely distorted using a simple pipe like so:

```bsh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glimagesink
```

This pipeline produces what you would expect in X but not when invoked from outside of X.

Pipelines involving a videomixer element will produce a background with a solid color:

```bsh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videomixer ! glimagesink
```

Both pipelines work with the fbdevsink without any issues and they also work perfectly when running them out of an X environment.

How can I make glimagesink to produce the same results no matter if I use it from X or without X?

**EDIT:**
Even after manually compiling, the results stay the same. I opened a [ticket in the gstreamer repo](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/issues/1204).

Turns out kmssink is also an option - no X needed, and performs way better than fbdevsink.

Comment: Quote: "*Both pipelines work [..] without any issues and they also work perfectly [..]*". So what is your question?

Comment: Well I want glimagesink to produce the same results no matter if I use it from X or without X.

Comment: Have you tried this on a non-RPi device?

Comment: @Beeblebrox no, unfortunately on my other machines the gstreamer bad plugins are compiled with X support only. Before compiling  them myself on the RPI I wanted to know if anyone else run into the same issue before.